# Store relational data in single proprietary file

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

In my application programming experience, I have always worked with a SQL Server (or Access) database on the back end that stores application data. I'm now looking at some business requirements that work with data that would fit well in a relational database, but they require it to be stored in a single, portable, custom file that the application will create, and load from. I know it's a very common concept for an application to save off a single file or document that it can later load and continue to work on, but I'm not sure how to achieve this with complex data. Encrypting xml comes to mind, but that would be very slow to work with or potentially eat up a lot of memory if I had to load it all back into objects first. What are some options?

Comment: What about SQLite ? its a single file based RDBMS

Comment: Is SQL Server Compact Edition no good for you?

Comment: Why do you have to encrypt the xml?

Comment: "portable" as in can be moved easily along with the application OR can be opened reasonably without the application (CSV/XML/...)?

Comment: @Habib.OSU & @ spender 1 - Sounds promising, I'm looking into them!

@ Anders Abel - The XML would have to be encrypted so it couldn't be tampered with or be human readable. Not much of a proprietary file if all I do is give an xml file my own extension was my thinking.

@ Alexei Levenkov - Good question. As in it can be easily moved. E-mailed between computers, or shared on a website or file share, and opened on any computer by the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running in a .NET environment I think that [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) is worth looking into. It is basically a mini SQL Server that doesn't have to be installed and configured as a service, but instead is an dll that you reference. You can use normal data access tools like linq-to-sql and entity framework.

Comment: +1 beat me to it, and he is already familiar with the MSSQL family.

Comment: @Anders Abel - This sounds like it will work unless any of the following are not true. 1. An .sdf can be created at runtime. 2. The .sdf can use a custom file extension. 3. The .sdf can use a password to prevent someone in possession of the file from opening it and gaining access to the data. I've read these are all true, please let me know if that is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you use a SQLLite or Firebird embedded database. There are other options as well. They support single-file usage and will give you a clear upgrade path for future versions of you schema (upgrade SQL scripts).

I did not understand how encryption plays into this.

Comment: Believe this is also a valid answer, but I prefer the MS approach in this case. +1 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) comes to my mind. Its a single file based DB. Here is a link to [convert SQL server databases to SQLite](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB). Also check out [Using SQLite in your C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application)